# Term for a person who complains about his supervisor to organization

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the right term meaning synonym for a person who complained about his/her boss or supervisor to the organization that they are working. That is the person. Finds out his supervisor's instructions are not relevant to the work and so stops following and inform the organization

Comment: You’ll need to provide some more context.  Is this viewed as a good thing or a bad thing?

Answer (score 4):

The term for this type of behaviour is:

*going over your boss's head*.

> go over somebody's head
>
> 1. to deal with someone at a higher level I would occasionally go over my manager's head to complain to the top financial officer.

[(Farlex)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+over+head)

> to more important or powerful person in order to get what
>   you want
>
> I was furious that he went over my head and complained to my manager.

A noun for a person who acts in such a way would be:

***[insubordinate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/insubordinate)***

> adj.
>
> 1. not submitting to authority; disobedient.
>
> n.
>
> 2. a person who is insubordinate

[(Macmillan)](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/www.macmillandictionary.com/license/amp/dictionary/british/go-over-someone-s-head#ampshare=http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-over-someone-s-head)

Depending on just how irrelevant the instructions from the original supervisor were, for instance if they constituted negligence or malfeasance on the part of the supervisor, you could use the term:

***[whistle-blower](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whistleblower)***

> One who reveals wrongdoing within an organization to the public or to
>   those in positions of authority

(Farlex)

Comment: So: an over-his-bosses-head-goer??  OP wants a name for the person.

Comment: Good point Jim, I'll revise my answer

Comment: I like *whistle-blower*.

Comment: +1 for whistle-blower. That would have been my answer.